# Enable CORS in httpd.conf

Tags: javascript, html, apache, cors, httpd.conf

I'm developing a web application which makes `REST` calls to another web application outside its domain.

But whenever it tries to make the REST call, I'm facing `CORS` issue in chrome.

**Error:**

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know this question has been asked many times & I've tried many of the suggestions, but none of them is working for me.

I'm using `httpd` as the web server.

Below is the **httpd.conf** of my system.
I've added `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` inside `<Directory>`, as suggested [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html).

Please suggest.

*Thanks*

**httpd.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Require all granted
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/        # My local sonarqube URL
  ProxyPassReverse / http://myhost.com
  ErrorLog logs/sonar/error.log
  CustomLog logs/sonar/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Debian-based distros. enable mod_headers running

```
a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 reload
```

In CentOS & other RedHat based distros

edit config file read by apache like httpd.conf and add

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

and reload apache with `sudo service httpd restart`

and in httpd.conf or some file read by apache like apache2.conf, of files *.conf within the folders like sites-available/ or sites-enabled/

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

`*` or the domain or domains you desire

> Keep in mind this must be placed in the server that receive the
>   request, not the server that send the request, and restrictions are
>   made by browsers, not servers, see this:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

There is also another way instead of editing some .conf file that is creating a file at document root level called `.htaccess` and inside: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

Comment: I can't see Apache installed. I can only see httpd. Moreover to start the server I use `service httpd start`. Also a2enmod is not found on my machine. What will be the best option to do in this case. Shall I install a2enmod, or is there any other alternative?

Comment: @reiley It depends on operating system, but it's the same apache2 and httpd. About a2enmod it depends on operating system too read this https://nitstorm.github.io/blog/enabling-disabling-modules-sites-apache/ I think you should add LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so in httpd.conf

Comment: @reiley I suggest you first to try with .htaccess file because headers module is usually available by default

Comment: where do we add this below line in httpd.conf : 
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

Answer (score 1):

To enable CORS the following header directive can be used:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Answer (score -1):

In my experience this error is often returned if there is any issue with the API.

You should try testing your web application in Chrome without web security to see if the issue is really a CORS issue or not. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) for more information.